# Cake PHP Link Doesn't Display

Tags: php, cakephp

I have string like "Venditoris: Beware of Scams » Blog Archive » Trilegiant Complaints ..." in Database but when I try to display it ,It is not displaying.
So,I used **html_entity_decode** function but still it is not display.

I am Using cakePHP.below is my code to display that links.

```
echo $html->link(html_entity_decode(
    $listing_end_arr[$i]['Listing']['listing_title'],ENT_QUOTES),
    $listing_end_arr[$i]['Listing']['listing_url'],
    array('target'=>'_blank', 'style'=>'color:' 
          . $colorArr[$listing_end_arr[$i]['Listing']['listing_sentiment']])) ;
```

Please Help me.

Comment: Show us how you're trying to display it as the problem may actually be there not in this string (which only has a few &raquo; chars)

Comment: What happens when you do pr($listing_end_arr)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the CakePHP manual if you are using `$html->link` correctly. If so, `var_dump` the return value instead of `echo`ing it. If it is empty, do

```
var_dump( $listing_end_arr[$i]['Listing'] );
```

to see what the *Listing* key contains. If the desired content is not in the dump, you know the error is elsewhere; probably in fetching the string from where it is stored.

---

Also, instead of using `array[n][foo][bar][baz]`, consider assigning the subarray to a variable while looping over the array, e.g. `$listing = array[n][foo][bar]`, so you can just do `$listing[baz]`. This will dramatically increase readability of your code.

Answer (score 1):

inspect generated html first.. your code should echo a link, maybe it's just not visible (styling, color..).